# Grails 2.0 update select with submitToRemote and render

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I face a problem using Grails 2 *submitToRemote* tag.

The following code is what I use in the controller:

```
def getProposal = {
    def layouts = importService.getLayoutsFor(params.product as int)
    render(contentType: "text/xml") {
        for (layout in layouts) {
            option("${layout}")
        }
    }
}
```

and in the GSP:

```
<g:submitToRemote action="getProposal" update="layouts"
    onLoading="showProgress();" onComplete="hideProgress();"
    value="Do It" />
<select id="layouts" name="layout" required="">
</select>
```

Using jquery this results in:

```
showProgress();;jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:jQuery(this).parents('form:first').serialize(), url:'/app/controller/getProposal',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#layouts').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){},complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){hideProgress();}});return false
```

which not works and returns am error:

```
Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
```

But if I use another render method like:

```
render(status: 0, text: "<option value='1'>Layout 1</option>")
```

it works.

In both cases the expected answer is transmitted back.

I did not understand why it will not work with the first nicer method. Could anyone explain what I do wrong?

Thx

Edit:

I noted that if I use **render(contentType: "text/text")** instead it will work. May be it has something to do, that the xml is not properly formatted (no root node?). But why does it work in Grails 1.3.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails 1.3.7 had a different default javascript provider (prototype). The jquery ajax call trys to infer the type of the response based on what it receives